# XSL dynamic element name from parameter

Tags: xml, xaml, xslt

I want to make a xsl template that automatically generates a gradient background in XAML. In order to do this, I have a parameter $control, which should be concatenated in the element name to '.Background'. Example: I have a Canvas to which I want to add a gradient background, I have to add an element "Canvas.Background". For some reason this concatenation fails, no matter how I adjust it.

```
<xsl:template name="get-gradient-background">
 <xsl:param name="control"/>
 <xsl:param name="start-color"/>
 <xsl:param name="end-color"/>
 <xsl:param name="offset" select="1"/>
  <xsl:element name="concat($control, '.Background)">
<xsl:element name="LinearGradientBrush">
 <xsl:element name="GradientStop">
  <xsl:attribute name="Color"><xsl:value-of select="$start-color"/></xsl:attribute>
     </xsl:element>
<xsl:element name="GradientStop">
 <xsl:attribute name="Color"><xsl:value-of select="$end-color"/></xsl:attribute>
     <xsl:attribute name="Offset"><xsl:value-of select="$offset"/></xsl:attribute>
</xsl:element>
   </xsl:element>
  </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>
```

Expected outcome (for a Canvas):

```
     <Canvas.Background>
      <LinearGradientBrush>
       <GradientStop Color="#FF93C5E8" />
       <GradientStop Color="#FF3B596E" Offset="1" />
      </LinearGradientBrush>
     </Canvas.Background>
```

Edit:

```
<xsl:template name="get-gradient-background">
 <xsl:param name="control"/>
 <xsl:param name="start-color"/>
 <xsl:param name="end-color"/>
 <xsl:param name="offset" select="1"/>
 <xsl:element name="concat({$control}, '.Background)">
  <xsl:element name="LinearGradientBrush">
   <xsl:element name="GradientStop">
    <xsl:attribute name="Color">
     <xsl:value-of select="$start-color"/>
    </xsl:attribute>
   </xsl:element>
   <xsl:element name="GradientStop">
    <xsl:attribute name="Color">
     <xsl:value-of select="$end-color"/>
    </xsl:attribute>
    <xsl:attribute name="Offset">
     <xsl:value-of select="$offset"/>
    </xsl:attribute>
   </xsl:element>
  </xsl:element>
 </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>
```

Another thing I've tried:

```
<xsl:element name="{concat($control, '.Background)}">
```

Answer (score 2):

If  you are using a variable, the element name must be wrapped in a Attribute Value Template (Curly Brackets)

```
<xsl:element name="{concat($control, '.Background')}">
```

Comment: You don't strictly need the "concat" here, you could shorten this to just `<xsl:element name="{$control}.Background" />`.

Comment: True (and good point), but my emphases was on using a Attribute Value Template and not shortening the OP's code

Comment: I've tried both suggestions, but am still getting 'Invalid element name. Invalid QName {, '.Background'}

Comment: Please update the original post with a new edited version of your code. Don't overwrite the old one. Also provide the current output.